# Replace a xtick by a letter in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm very new to the TikZ environment. I'm trying to replace the "4" in the following graph by a Greek letter (ideally a `\tau^{*}`). Any idea ?
Thanks in advance

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
            gamma(\x)= 0.25*\x*\x*exp(-0.5*\x);
    }
]

\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=1:13, samples=200,
  axis lines*=left, xlabel=$\tau$, ylabel=$V(\tau)$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  xtick={4}, ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
  grid = major,    
  xmin=0, ymin=0,
]
\addplot [very thick,cyan] {gamma(x)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```
xticklabel={$\tau^{\ast}$},
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
            gamma(\x)= 0.25*\x*\x*exp(-0.5*\x);
    }
]

\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=1:13, samples=200,
  axis lines*=left, xlabel=$\tau$, ylabel=$V(\tau)$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  xtick={4}, 
  xticklabel={$\tau^{\ast}$},
  ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
  grid = major,    
  xmin=0, ymin=0,
]
\addplot [very thick,cyan] {gamma(x)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `xticklabels={<list>}` you can supply a list of tick labels to each tick assigned using `xtick`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
            gamma(\x)= 0.25*\x*\x*exp(-0.5*\x);
    }
]

\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=1:13, samples=200,
  axis lines*=left, xlabel=$\tau$, ylabel=$V(\tau)$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  xtick={4, 6}, 
  xticklabels={$\tau^{\ast}$, $\gamma$},
  ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
  grid = major,    
  xmin=0, ymin=0,
]
\addplot [very thick,cyan] {gamma(x)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]